# Jenkins build periodically every 15 days on monday

Tags: jenkins, cron

How to scehdule jenkins build every 15 days on monday ?

https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/setting-up-the-cron-jobs-in-jenkins-using-build-periodically-scheduling-the-jenins-job/

tried with cron('30 6 */15 * 1') but doesn't return desired result.

Comment: So if the 15th day is not a Monday what do you want to do?

Comment: only on monday.

Comment: If the 15th day falls on a day that is not Monday, then what you want to do? Do you want like, The cron job will not run on that day. It will then run on next nearest(upcoming) Monday?